# Express.js takes excesive time to handle 1000 simple requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, express, performance-testing

I'm testing the performance of my express.js server application and it takes too much time(up to 15 seconds) to handle 1000 simple requests.

I've coded a simple nodejs express api in order to implement it in a future really big load intensive api. The api works flawless but once I got my hands into big amounts of concurrent requests, the performance was not the expected.
In the future the expected scenario is thousands of users sending requests in a matter of 1-5 seconds nonstop, so this is a crucial part.

I coded another script to send 50, 500, 1000.... requests almost instantly from my own workstation(localhost, packets dont reach the net) and set the api to handle the request and just answer with "OK".

```
var express = require('express');

var super_router = express.Router();

super_router.use('/playground', function(req, res, next){
    res.json('OK');
});
```

The time it takes to handle 100 requests is 3 seconds, 500 requests 15 seconds and so on in the same proportion.
The expected performance is not the desired taking into account the cpu never reaches 50%.
I've also tried splitting the amount of requests to send in more sender scripts but the outcome is exactly the same.

Are these the expected numbers for Express.js without clustering?

The script I'm using to test:

```
var request = require('request');

let url = "http://localhost:3000/playground";


let requestsNumber = 5000;

(async () => {
    try {

        console.log(' ## INIT ##');
        let date0 = new Date().getTime();


        await makeAllRequests();

        console.log('Elapsed ms: '+(new Date().getTime()-date0));
        console.log('DONE')

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();

async function makeAllRequests(){

    let promises = [];

    for(let i=0;i<requestsNumber;i++){
        promises.push(makeRequest());
    }

    console.log('Finish sending requests')
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

async function makeRequest(){

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        request.get(
            url,
            function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {

                if (err){
                    console.error('Error:', err);
                }
                resolve();
            });
    })
}
```

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: It's another standalone script that generates a given amount(10,100,1000...) of requests by storing promises inside an array. It executes quite fast in less than a second.

Comment: I don't get why you say it takes 15 seconds for your server to process all 1000 requests and your script only takes 1 second to make all requests.

Comment: No, these are not the expected results. My NodeJS server answers in < 5ms (and multiple in parallel), even for more complex API queries. My bet is that your script performing the load test does something wrong. Have you tried pinging with Postman?

Comment: The script takes less than a second to cast all the requests to the server, then it starts waiting for the server to answer all the petitions. The server is the one slowly answering to each these individual requests.

Comment: Well, share the script so we can see what you are doing or use another tool like [Artillery](https://artillery.io/) or [Vegeta](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta) and then post results you get from them.

Comment: posted the script

Comment: How certain are you that the requests actually go right when you ask? In a browser, you can make 1000 parallel 'requests', but they block at 6 or so actual network-traffic level requests at any given time
EDIT: Seems to be dependent on the version of nodejs: https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/concurrent-http-connections-in-node-js/

Comment: But did you enable `NODE_ENV="production"` ? This [dramatically speeds things up](https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/the-drastic-effects-of-omitting-node-env-in-your-express-js-applications/)

Comment: Yes, its set inside the code, i know its not the correct way for environment variables:
app.set('env','production');

Comment: @Tiburoncito I tried running your scripts on my machine, but I got very different numbers. For 1000 requests it takes a bit more than 1 second. If I use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost it reduces by almost half, which is understandable, cause the DNS lookup will happen for every single request. It might be useful to know how your are initialising the actual express app. The code you posted is only the router.